# I have no idea how to solve this problem using areas of known cross section

Tags: area, volume, cross-sections

[The problem involving cross sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjMzX.png)

I am so confused on how to find volume using known cross sections. I've never understood it. This problem that I've encountered is very difficult, and I tried using the formula of the area of an isosceles triangle, but I don't know where to go from there. I would be so grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the $y$ for the lower and upper curve at specific $x$. Since the cross section for fixed $x$ is a right angle isosceles triangle, its area  $A(x) = \frac12(y_2(x)-y_1(x))^2$. What you can do is compute the integral $\int_0^2 A(x) dx$ directly. Since this is an MC question, you can eliminate most answer by inspection.. It is not that hard to rule out $(C)$ and $(D)$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 4\cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right)$ and $g(x) = (x-2)^2$

Our cross sections are *isosceles right triangles*, so our legs are the same length, and it is given that a leg lies in $R$ and is perpendicular to the $x$ axis.

The area of a isosceles right triangle is $\frac12 \ell^2$ where $\ell$ is the length of the leg.

Therefore the area of the isosceles right triangle is $ \frac12 (f(x) - g(x) )^2 = \frac12 \left((x-2)^2 -4\cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right) \right)^2$

Now we integrate from $x=0$ to $x=2$ as shown:

$$\int_0^2 \frac12 \left((x-2)^2 -4\cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right) \right)^2 dx$$

Evaluating the integral by hand isn't pretty, but certainly doable, and through [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E2+%5Cfrac12+%5Cleft((x-2)%5E2+-4%5Ccos+%5Cleft(+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi+x%7D%7B4%7D+%5Cright)+%5Cright)%5E2+dx) we see that this integral simplifies down to about $1.775$

Comment: Oh my god! I totally get it now. Thanks! Just one question; why did we subtract g(x) from f(x) and not the other way around? Plus, I don't need to evaluate the integral, it's a calculator section :P

Comment: Because in the range of $x=0$ to $x=2$ the function $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$. In other words, $f(x)$ is on top and $g(x)$ is on the bottom